# Inflating a second alert dialogBox on top of a first one?

Tags: java, android, dialog, android-alertdialog

- User tabs save icon
- First alert dialog pops up, asking for name to save as
- User inputs the name, tabs on "Save" button
- The system detects that a file with the same name already exists in the data base
- The system pops up a 2nd alert dialog, asking for confirmation of override from the user.
- The app crashes when I try to inflate the 2nd dialog.

That's what I'm trying to do. At the point everything works until the when I try to inflate the 2nd alert dialog, the app crushes. So I guess that's not how I should do it.

So how do I do this?

See my code:

```
 public void saveFingering() { //THIS IS WHAT'S BEING EXECUTED IF THE USER TABS SAVE ON THE FIRST ALERT DIALOG)
      ...
        if (isFileNew == true) {
            myDB.insertData(mapName, bStateStr, pitchStateStr, nodeHeight, nodeNote);
        } else
        { 
            showSaveConfirmDialog(mapName); //THIS IS FOR THE 2ND ALERT DIALOG
         ...
        }

  }
 public void showSaveConfirmDialog(String mapName) {

        DialogFragment confirmDialogue = new ConfirmSavingDialogueFragment();

        confirmDialogue.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "ConfirmSavingDialogueFragment");
  }

 public class ConfirmSavingDialogueFragment extends DialogFragment {
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            saveConfirmDialogueView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_save_confirm, null); //CRUSH HERE
             ...
        }
  }
```

Comment: Dismiss the first dailog before opening the second One

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that!

Answer (score 0):

Is your first dialog is also `DialogFragment`? Does 1st dialog is being dismissed before inflating 2nd dialog?

Comment: Yes, and no. Thanks, that gives me some idea. I'll try to dismiss the first dialogue before calling the 2nd one.